# Read array of bytes from a text file (.txt)

Tags: c++, arrays, byte

I'm coding a program in C++ and I've a text file with a pattern/array of bytes that I want to scan in the memory of a random process (I'm using Windows).

Content inside `File.txt:`

```
\x55\x8B\xEC\x83\x44\x0C\x7C\xDF
```

I managed to read this string and print it with printf() perfectly, but when I pass this string as a const char* to my pattern scan function, its not returning the address of the function in the random process I said.

A curious test I made was this:

```
DWORD function_address = findpattern(module_from_random_process_here, "\x55\x8B\xEC\x83\x44\x0C\x7C\xDF", mask);
```

**->** Note that I'm hardcoding my pattern inside it, and not using the one I've read inside `File.txt`.

It returned the correct memory address, but if I put the pattern I've read from my `File.txt`, the address can't be found in the memory of the process I'm scanning. But the thing is, when I print the pattern I've read from the text file, it's showing correctly!

Another thing: I made another tests too, and if I read the mask from my `File.txt` and use the one I've read inside the findpattern call, it works (just the pattern "isn't working").

Something makes me think that it's something related to read whats inside my File.txt as hex, but I'm with problems to make it work.

Info: to read the pattern inside File.txt I'm simple using `std::ifstream` and `std::geline(File.txt, strPattern)`

Comment: Note that backslash has special meaning in `c++` literals but not in generic text files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! How do you suggest me to fix it? I'm trying to fix it for like 10 hours, since yesterday :(

Comment: A literal string like `"\x55"` is converted by the compiler into a string that consists of the character with the byte value 0x55. If your file contains this string you must write logic to make that same conversion of the strings that you read from it.

Answer (score 0):

When reading a file you should always consider it's encoding. Different Chars in the file can be interpreted as different hex values.
for example lets take the string \x55\x8B. It can be casted to different **number** of chars according to the different encoding. It could be two chars if you use a 8 bit encoding or maybe 1 char if you decided to use a 16 bits encoding system.

If I understood correctly you want the string \x55\x8B to be 8 chars. And if so, we need to understand which encoding your file is using. You wrote that the file contains the string `\x55\x8B\xEC\x83\x44\x0C\x7C\xDF`. Is it the binary data? is it utf-8? maybe ascii? each one of the option will have different binary representation.

Edit:
according to the comments you need a logic that turns a binary value of \x65 to the string "\x65". This can be used:

```
int a = 0x65;
std::string str = "\\x" + std::to_string((a >> 4) & 0xFF) + std::to_string(a & 0x0F);
```

Also adding here the other side of casting, maybe this will be handy. If you need to cast a string "\x65" to its value use this:

```
std::string str= "\\x65";
std::stringstream ss;
int x;
ss << std::hex << str.substr(str.find('x')+1);
ss >> x;
```

Comment: My File.txt is encoded in utf-8. \x55\x8B needs to represent 2x bytes, because the findpattern function scans all the process memory (byte by byte) to see the region that matches with my pattern, and then, it returns the memory address. This is what I want to do.

Comment: so if you have "\x55" in your file and you will open the file with notepad (or any other simple viewer) you should see something that starts with U?

Comment: When I open my File.txt with notepad++ it's what appears (exactly what I wrote): \x55\x8B\xEC\x83\x44\x0C\x7C\xDF

Comment: check how many chars you read from the file. If it is 32 chars, so I think that the problem is somewhere else. If it is 32 chars so use my second code snip to convert it to its binary form and send this as char* to your function.
you can also check if the read value from the file is equal to the hardcoded value if this test will be true the problem is somewhere else...